# add touch event to a uibutton when it comes in parents visible area

Tags: ios, uibutton, touch-event

I have a button which currently is not inside parents visible area or rather in the area where touch events can occur.

So when i animate that button inside parents bound i want to add it a touch event. So anyone has idea about it ?

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Set button's userInteractionEnabled property to NO initially and when you want it to be able to act on touch events set this to YES